# How to make Regular gaps/holes on a wall?

Tags: modeling

I want to model the great wall of China, but meet some difficulty with these gaps on the wall. As you can see in the picture below, there is a lot of regular holes and gaps on the wall left and right side wall.
[image]
<sub>(source: [worldalldetails.com](http://worldalldetails.com/sightseeing/great_wall_china_245489.jpg))</sub>

and here is my idea on this object, I want to use a path and bevel it with another curve (the unselected one). Although this gives me a approximate shape, but without these holes and gaps in the real photo.
[image]
Is there any tech or addon script helps? Thanks for any suggestion.

===================
New problem:
[image]

Comment: You can create one segment with all the details, then add array modifier and curve modifier to follow the selected curve.

Comment: @Denis it looks very well when the curve is approximately to be a line, but when the curve is really 'curve', segments will change their shape slightly. How should I fix that?

Comment: Can you add a snapshot where you have the problem?

Comment: @Denis The screenshot have added.

Comment: You can't avoid distortion while bending the object, you can do shape correction after applying the modifiers.

Comment: @Denis okay, but I want to give texture to the single segment as it is harder to map uv for a curve object, do shape correction will change the texture, is there any better method to map this curve object?

Comment: @DavidPage why won't you just texture the model first then add the modifier later on?, and i think your model is too big (z axis) so the distortion is occur to happen.

Comment: @noob.blenderhead I mean how to avoid texture changing caused by shape correction.

Comment: @DavidPage Correct me if i'm wrong, but couldn't you just re-project the model (that have been shape corrected) with the texture and edit it in uv/image editor (i think you need to rephrase your question for easier understanding on the community part :])

Comment: @noob.blenderhead oh, you are right. It's my misunderstanding. Thank you.

Comment: @Denis I found I cannot move the wall properly. after I set the modifiers, press g ,x and move my mouse it moves along the curve but not along the x axis. How does that happen?